# Fisher Information Matrix of log-normal parameters

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

I'm trying to find asymptotic variances of the parameters of log-normal.

Assume $ X \sim LN(\mu,\sigma), f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}x}e^{-\frac{(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $ and we have $ n $ observations

Let $ \theta = (\mu, \sigma)' $ and the Fisher information is

$
\begin{eqnarray}
 I(\theta) &=& E \left[ \left\{ \frac{\partial \ln f_\theta(x)}{\partial \theta}\right\}\left\{\frac{\partial \ln f_\theta(x)}{\partial \theta} \right\} ' \right] \\ &=&E \left[ \left( \begin{array}{c} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (\ln x_i-\mu)}{\sigma^2} \\ \frac{-n}{\sigma} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (\ln x_i-\mu)^2}{\sigma^3}  \end{array} \right) 
\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (\ln x_i-\mu)}{\sigma^2}\ \ \  \frac{-n}{\sigma} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (\ln x_i-\mu)^2}{\sigma^3}  \right) \right]
\end{eqnarray} $

My textbook says this yields
$ \left( \begin{array}{rr}  \frac{n}{\sigma^2}  &  0 \\ 0 &  \frac{\sigma^2}{2n}   \end{array} \right)$.

I'm stuck in the expected value calculation. How should I take the expected from 
$ \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (\ln x_i-\mu)}{\sigma^2} \right)^2 $, for example? I also don't see why these two components are zero.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It suffices to find the information matrix for a single observation and then multiply it by $n$ for the sample of $n$ observations. According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), the information matrix for the sample has the 2 x 2 element $\frac{n}{2\sigma^4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $Z_i:=\frac{\ln X_i-\mu}{\sigma}\sim N(0,\,1)$,$$EZ_i^2Z_j^2=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
1 & i\ne j\\
3 & i=j
\end{array}\right.=1+2\delta_{ij},$$and you can similarly show $EZ_iZ_j=\delta_{ij},\,EZ_iZ_j^2=0$. Your outer product can be rewritten as$$\frac{1}{\sigma}\sum_{i}\left(\begin{array}{c}
Z_{i}\\
Z_{i}^{2}-1
\end{array}\right)\frac{1}{\sigma}\sum_{j}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
Z_{j} & Z_{j}^{2}-1\end{array}\right)\\=\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}\sum_{ij}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
Z_{i}Z_{j} & Z_{i}Z_{j}^{2}-Z_{i}\\
Z_{i}^{2}Z_{j}-Z_{j} & Z_{i}^{2}Z_{j}^{2}-Z_{i}^{2}-Z_{j}^{2}+1
\end{array}\right),$$with mean$$\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}\sum_{ij}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\delta_{ij} & 0\\
0 & 2\delta_{ij}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{n}{\sigma^{2}} & 0\\
0 & \frac{2n}{\sigma^{2}}
\end{array}\right).$$Your textbook appears to have the last fraction upside down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I get $ E Z_i^2 Z_j^2 = 1+2 \delta_{ij} $ ? Do I need integration?

Comment: I found it. When $ j=i $, it’s 4th moment of Z, which is 3, and when $ j \neq i $, it’s a product of 2nd moment of Z, which is $ EZ_i^2 \cdot EZ_j^2 = 1 $. Is this right?

Comment: @Roki Yes, that's it.